# Vim, python3 und syntastic

Tags: python, vim, syntastic

The python script runs well so I'm wondering about syntastics complains.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
syntastic: [no-member] Module 'numpy.random' has no 'seed' member

random_walk = [0]
syntastic: [invalid-name] Invalid constant name "random_walk"
```

env:

- python 3.5.2
- vim 8.0.66
- windows 8

I added

```
let g:syntastic_python_python_exec = 'c:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python.exe'
let g:syntastic_python_checkers = ['pylint']
```

to my _vimrc but it doesn't make any change.

Comment: 1. `g:syntastic_python_python_exec` is not relevant to the `pylint` checker. See the [FAQ](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic#faqpython) if you want to run Anaconda. 2. You're barking at the wrong tree, syntastic doesn't know, nor cares, about the contents of your files. Enable debugging (see `:h syntastic-debug`) to find out what options are passed to `pylint`, then ask why does `pylint` complain about your code with said options.

Comment: You're absolutely right I was on the completely wrong track. I need to investigate on pylint.